# Pkg-config missing many pc files

Tags: libraries, pkg-config

I have been trying to compile gargoyle and keep getting the fallowing error.

```
Package fontconfig was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fontconfig.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fontconfig' found
```

Also for freetype2, gdk-x11-2.0, and gtk+-x11-2.0.

I could compile on 12.20 so I copied the files over and tried again. It complained about more files.

Why are so many of my libraries missing their pc files? I have the -dev packages installed.

Comment: I am really confused by all this -dev packages thing. For example -dev package for fontconfig appeared to have name libfontconfig1-dev. Who on earth decides about such messy and not-intuitive names?...